# how to make a modal QProgressDialog in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, qt5, qprogressdialog

I am calling QProgressDialog from a thread and am unable to make it as a modal window even though I set the setModal to true. I want mainwindow to be blocked when QProgressDialog is in action.

following is my piece of code.

GenericFunc.h
`QProgressDialog *progressBarDialog;`

GenericFunc.cpp

```
     void GenericFunc::testSlot()
    {
        int numTasks = 4500;
        progressBarDialog = new QProgressDialog("Task in progress.", "Cancel", 0, numTasks);
        progressBarDialog->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
        progressBarDialog->setModal(true);
        progressBarDialog->exec();
    }
```

Comment: The slot is being called from another QThread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QProgressDialog class is a GUI class. You cannot instantiate that in the worker thread.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

> GUI Thread and Worker Thread
>
> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

Use signal slots to pass the progress data from worker thread to gui thread.

Another issue is that you set this to WindowModal, but this `progressBarDialog` doesn't have any parent, so it is not going to block any parent window(s) chain.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum

Comment: Thanks, I created a slot in mainwindow and emitting a signal from the worker thread, further I set WindowModality to ApplicationModal and by this way being able to block the parent window.